# HP DEskjet 2700 printer options

Tags: printing

I have installed the HP Deskjet 2700 printer that is wireless and on my computer it is installed with CUPS, although I think it uses the HP driver.   But I don't have the option to see, for example, the level of the inks or any other option.  I think I need to install the HPLIP Tools, but I'm not sure about anything and I need some help.  
I have Ubuntu 22.04 installed on a Dell 13 9310 laptop
Thanks

Comment: " I think I need to install the HPLIP Tools" and "although I think it uses the HP driver" don't mix: you use the cups driver and want hplip to use the hp driver. The hp driver implies hplip. Get the download from the official HP website and follow the readme: it is very very detailed and has a very VERY long install.

Comment: Read the printer's manual. Ink levels can be checked from the control panel or from the Embedded Web server (EWS).

Comment: I have installed HPLIP, including the last version, it discovers the printer but can't open HP Tools

Comment: you should be able to identify the IP address of the printer (usually you can set the IP address within the printer panel). After which in your browser, enter the IP address (such as 192.168.1.nn) and you should be able to see the printer options from there.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't find the IP address of the printer, but I found a way to see the ink level, at least the status. Thanks for your help.

Comment: if the printer is connected by WiFi, your router (often 19.2.168.1.1 by default in your web browser) should give you connected devices by IP address.

Comment: OK, thanks, but I think I have found some solution

Comment: My problem with installation of HPLIP are the missing dependencies. The process can't find the downloads and of course cant install them.

Comment: does [this reference](https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-hplip-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts/) help you with installing HPLIP on v22.04?

Comment: No, I already tried twice and when installing the dependencies, it fails.

Comment: The problem I have with the installation of HPLIP is with additional, which can not download and install